# Django Forms DateInput widget not populating

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a django edit form that has many fields from a model including some date fields, for a suitable format, I used a DateInput widget. Unfortunately, when we edit the object, all other fields are already populated with existing data, but the dates. The dates are in their initial state (dd/mm/yyyy) and since they are required, the user has to reenter the dates everytime they want to edit the object, even if they do not want to change the dates.

does anyone have an idea on how to prepopulate the date data in these date fields?

forms.py:

```
 class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
        input_type = 'date'
        input_formats = ('%d-%m-%Y')
    [...]
 date_sinistre = forms.DateField(widget=DateInput, label='Date sinistre')
 date_effet = forms.DateField(widget=DateInput, label='Date effet')
 date_echeance = forms.DateField(widget=DateInput, label='Date échéance')
```

edit_object.html:

```
    <div class='row border border-primary rounded m-1 border-3'>
            <div class='col-md-4 p-0 pl-2 pr-2 justify-content-center align-self-center'>
                <strong>DATE DE SINISTRE:</strong>
            </div>
            <div class='col-md-8 p-0 pl-2 pr-0 justify-content-center align-self-center'>
                {{ dossierForm.date_sinistre|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class='row border border-primary rounded m-1 border-3'>
            <div class='col-md-4 p-0 pl-2 pr-2 justify-content-center align-self-center'>
                <strong>DATE EFFET:</strong>
            </div>
            <div class='col-md-8 p-0 pl-2 pr-0 justify-content-center align-self-center'>
                {{ dossierForm.date_effet|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class='row border border-primary rounded m-1 border-3'>
            <div class='col-md-4 p-0 pl-2 pr-2 justify-content-center align-self-center'>
                <strong>DATE ÉCHÉANCE:</strong>
            </div>
            <div class='col-md-8 p-0 pl-2 pr-0 justify-content-center align-self-center'>
                {{ dossierForm.date_echeance|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
    </div>
```

PS: although I specified the format to be dd-mm-yy, the widget still displays the date as MM-DD-YYYY.

Screenshot: [image]

Comment: Shouldn't you implement `input_formats` as a tuple, so `input_formats = ('%d-%m-%Y',)` (with a comma)?

Answer (score 1):

Your DateInput produces the element `<input type = "date">` but this kind of element works with the format `'%Y-%m-%d'`.

In fact, inspecting a correct HTML element, it should be like this:

```
<input type="date" name="date" value="2020-04-07" id="id_date">
```

Since your're passing a date in another format, the initial value is ignored.

The following should work

```
class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
        input_type = 'date'
        input_formats = ('%Y-%m-%d')
    [...]
 date_sinistre = forms.DateField(widget=DateInput, label='Date sinistre')
 date_effet = forms.DateField(widget=DateInput, label='Date effet')
 date_echeance = forms.DateField(widget=DateInput, label='Date échéance')
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the source code of the [**`DateInput`** and **`DateTimeBaseInput`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/forms/widgets.py#L475-L489), you need to specify the [**`format=…`** *parameter* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.DateInput.format) to the constructor:

> ```
> class DateTimeBaseInput(TextInput):
>     format_key = ''
>     supports_microseconds = False
>
>     def __init__(self, attrs=None, format=None):
>         super().__init__(attrs)
>         self.format = format or None
>
>     def format_value(self, value):
>         return formats.localize_input(value, self.format or formats.get_format(self.format_key)[0])
>
>
> class DateInput(DateTimeBaseInput):
>     format_key = 'DATE_INPUT_FORMATS'
>     template_name = 'django/forms/widgets/date.html'
> ```

You thus can implement this with:

```
    # …
    date_sinistre = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(format='%d-%m-%Y'), label='Date sinistre')
    date_effet = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(format='%d-%m-%Y'), label='Date effet')
    date_echeance = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(format='%d-%m-%Y'), label='Date échéance')
```

You furthermore should probably alter the [**`DATE_INPUT_FORMAT`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#date-input-formats) and add your `'%d-%m-%Y'` format as one of the acceptable formats.

Comment: How can I define TextInput?

Comment: from django.forms.widgets ?

Comment: @KaissBouali: you don't need to definine these, I was only *referring* to the source code of *Django* itself.

Comment: @KaissBouali: again, you do *not* need to define the `DateTimeBaseInput`, or the `DateInput`. The `DateInput` we are here using is the one from `django.forms`...

Comment: Still doesn't work buddy. I tried all what you have stated above and the datepicket widget goes away and only the date is shown as text field. I also tried tempus_dominus widget but again, nothing changes.